# Low cost external shutter for controlling shutter speed

Tags: canon, shutter-release

Are there any alternatives to the $400+ external shutter remote that can do auto bracketing for a canon 700D?

Basically some shutter + a click wheel that adjusts shutter speed without touching the camera (applicable in multi exposure situations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options on Amazon, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0081EC08M). The basic idea is you put the camera in bulb mode and use the **intervalometer** to control the shutter. Some may have AEB settings, or you can adjust it yourself.

Comment: Be aware that the *exact* Tv when using an external intervalometer may not be *precisely* the same as when the Tv is set using the camera. For example when set to 1/320 second my camera uses an actual Tv of 1/332 second. An external intervalometer may result in a faster or slower Tv, say 1/300 second. Be sure to do some test shots if exposure accuracy is critical.

Comment: the users for that product say you can not set the speed, only the intervals between what the camera is set to

Answer (score 1):

You can also skip the external intervalometer altogether and try [Magic Lantern](http://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#exposure-bracketing).  It supports exposure bracketing by the shutter or ISO.  It would be in camera and free.

Answer (score 0):

CamRanger is a good system, although pricey it also does quite a bit more that you may find useful.  [Here's some information](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AA478UQ)